# How to Share an audio to multiple iPhone users using QuickBlox from one iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio-streaming, broadcast, quickblox

I want to share my audio to my multiple friends at remote distance. I am able to do it for 1 - 1 devices, rather i want to do it for 1 - many devices(iPhones).
Please let me know if any other cloud backend provider allows this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to do it in real time or just upload file to server and send it to multiple friends?

Comment: @IgorKhomenko : Thanks for reply.
i want to do it in real time. You can think of a radio as an example.
I have used TokBox and QuickBlox but unable to figure out my intention (1 to Many in real time).

Comment: QuickBlox is going to release this feature in the nearest iOS SDK release, please keep in touch with our blog quickblox.com/blog

Comment: @IgorKhomenko: Thanks for help...Looking forward to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuickBlox released GroupVideo Chat (beta), check it out here http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-videochat-ios